# Magento - how to remove "addLinkRel"

Tags: magento

I've created a child theme, with 'rwd' as the parent theme. The parent theme has this code in the 'head' block in page.xml:

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
```

is there a way of removing it in the child theme in local.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your `local.xml` file

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</name></action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not obvious but it is quite easy.

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
```

Comment: This worked too, I chose the other answer as the correct answer, as it included the 'head' reference.